# Eclipse change src folder to src/main/java permanently

Tags: java, eclipse, settings

Is it possible to change the `src` path of Java-Projects in Eclipse to `src/main/java` permanently. I know how to do it for one project or an entire workspace, but is there a solution to do it once for each future workspace or do I have to go to the preferences every time and set it manually?

Answer (score 0):

1)-Go to the "Environment Variables" on your PC (Advanced Control Panel option), just search the term in your PC to do so.

2)-Click the "Environment Variables" on the right bottom of the opened window.

3)-U will see 2 sub windows, ideally you should edit only in the lower window, but I suggest do identical changes IN both the windows as follows.

3.1)- click on PATH and set yr desired path as u mentioned in your question (to the javaw.exe file in your bin in the JDK).
  3.2)- create a JAVA_HOME variable if it doesn't already exists and ensure it marks to the JDK.

Comment: I only have my mobile phone with me at the moment, but it looks like Windows only, is that right? I prefers Unix and at home I only have a Mac, is there a solution too?

Comment: @ProbstDJakob I have only used a PC and that too Windows OS.Any further query requires RnD. Moreover I don't want to post anything I am not completely sure of.